# Combining diminutive/augmentative suffixes

Tags: sufijos

I've heard that a combination of two (or more) of the same suffixes is possible (*chiquititita*).

Is it possible two combine two different suffixes with the same meaning? Is the word *chiquitín* produced this way?

What about combining a diminutive and an augmentative suffix to produce a word? That won't make sense, or will it (maybe to express irony or something)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never heard 'chiqui**ti**tita', although I have heard people using suffixes in the way you describe.

The root of that word would be [chiquito/ta](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=6oYHjq7OBDXX2dHJ8lw3), so you could form 'chiquit**ito**' (no extra 'ti'). As you can see in the definition the word itself is the diminutive form of *chico* (which can be understood also as an adjetive meaning "small")

With "chiquit**ito**" you would be adding a diminutive to a word that already depicts something small or tiny, but you are not really adding two sets of diminutives to "chico".

You could use other suffixes to enhance the meaning of other suffix.

> pequeñitísimo (pequeño -> pequeñ**ito** -> pequeñit**ísimo**)

Nevertheless, I have heard "pequeñitito", which I guess is formed in the way you describe

> pequeñitito (pequeño -> pequeñ**ito** -> pequeñit**ito** or pequeñit**ico**)

so I guess such combination may be possible, although not with all suffixes. Also probably this usage may be understood as colloquial and not as something that adheres to the *best practices* of the grammar (favor `pequeñísimo` over "pequeñitísimo").

For the same same reason, using augmentative and diminutive suffixes for the same word may be possible in  colloquial Spanish. Just imagine that you see the baby of a friend of yours, and this baby (*chiquito*) has grown a lot since the last time you saw him, and you want to convey that the *pequeñín* is a "big small kid":

> Qué guapo está este chiquit**ote**!

Or if your friend had kittens (*gatitos*) and one was much bigger than the rest:

> Eso no es un gatito, es un gatit**ote**!!

Again, this usage is completely colloquial, and the context may be carrying a lot of information that helps to think such words may be just fine to express the idea.

Comment: _Grandotote_ is common in colloquial Spanish in Chile. Note that all the examples are related with 'big' and 'small'. Not works with _casitita_ or _caballitito_.

Comment: My girlfriend says "gatititito" for a very small kitten. In Mexico you can heard casitita, caballitito, gatotote, even you can hear caserón or caseronón (ver big house). As Diego says, is possible, but it's not the best use of grammar. You will hear that only in very informal conversations.

But I have never heard a diminutive and an augmentative in the same word.

Comment: Of course, all this repetition of diminutives immediately reminds us Mexicans. Are you the boyfriend of "La Chilindrina"?

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's question about mixing diminutive with augmentative suffixes at all.

Comment: @Paul, it addresses _"Is it possible two combine two different suffixes with the same meaning?"_. If there is more than one question in there maybe they should have been posted separated as such, but I opted for answering instead of asking this user to [rewrite his/her question **again**](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11814/5481). It can be easily inferred that, as mixing suffixes of the same kind, such constructions are possible in colloquial Spanish, but I'll update que answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Rodrigo, jajajaj buena esa

Answer (score 2):

In Mexico is very common to add extra ***ti*** for diminutives. So your example *chiquititita* is completely acceptable in everyday speech: ***Chiquita*** > ***Chiquitita*** > ***Chiquititita*** > ***Chiquitititita***; the same for augmentatives can be: ***Grande*** > ***Grandísimo*** > ***Grandisísimo*** > ***Grandisisísimo***. You can hear this a lot in *El chavo del ocho*.

***Chiquitín*** is not the combination of different suffixes. **-ín** is actually a suffix: ***Chico*** > ***Chiquitín***; ***Pequeño*** > ***Pequeñín***. Usually with this suffix the word with ***-ín*** gets a new meaning becoming a separate word but with a very related significance: ***Botica***[old word for drugstore] > ***Botiquín***[first aid kit]; ***Maleta***[Suitcase] > ***Maletín***[Briefcase]. In the opposite, ***-ón*** is an augmentative: ***Balón***[ball] > ***Bala***[bullet] < ***Balín***[pellet].

***Gatitote*** is something people don't say in Mexico, by the comments apparently in other countries is normal but not here. Here we would say: ***Gatote*** > ***Gatotote*** > ***Gatototote***

About combinating different suffixes, well, I think it depends a lot of the context but I think it is not very common.

Comment: The description of *chiquitín* seems inaccurate - I think the OP was implying *chico > chiquito > chiquitín*, which **is** the combination of two suffixes: *chico + ito + ín*.

Answer (score 1):

I have on ocasion heard it used conversationally in Mexico in words such as

> chiquitote

used, for example to refer to a child that has grown a lot.

It is usable and understandable but I would not consider it correct spanish.